# Laravel 9 mail on production get only this error - Expected response code "250" but got code "451"

Tags: laravel, amazon-sqs, mailer

We've upgraded our application to Laravel 9 last week and noticed a large amount of failed jobs appearing as soon as we deployed the build in production.

Those errors were all email related with the following error message:

```
Expected response code "250" but got code "451", with message "451 4.4.2 Timeout waiting for data from client.".
```

We've reverted back to the previous build (which was using SwiftMailer) and the errors stopped. To clarify, we've been running the application for a few weeks and never had that error before.

On "Staging" we didn't have that issue. The only difference is we use SQS for queues in live and set :

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
```

that are the only differences.

Comment: Exactly the same issue here.  Also, are you using Amazon SES by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But needed to back it to SMTP because BCC didn't work in SES :(

Comment: I am using BCC but I am sending via smtp using SES.  We aren't using SQS for a queue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could you try adding `'ping_threshold' => 10,` to your `smtp` or `ses` configuration in `config/mail.php`

If you are using a queue worker/manager, remember to restart the process for the new configuration to come into effect.

This seems to have resolved the issue for me.  Could be coincidental, but will report back if the issue returns.

Comment: I found that this also fixed it for me - I set it to both ses and smtp in mailer array in mail.php. Strange...

Comment: Scratch that... didn't fix my issue which started with the L9 upgrade from L8

Comment: That's a shame, it has fixed it for me (also L9 upgrade from L8) but we are using SES over SMTP and not SQS

Comment: Seems that it fixed the problem. Was running jobs as a daemon.

Comment: Could you mark answer as correct, to help others

Comment: Sorry, MrCarrot. I think that I do that. But looks like I forgot that. Sorry.

Comment: The SwiftMailer implementation [forced reconnections after each message](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/38481/files#diff-2310168aa86b70a22595ba784039cbdde829bd38245c9586eedd111dfd0f806dL523). To reproduce this exact behaviour, [you can specify `'restart_threshold' => 1,`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/96c2e10395d3e699c8a3cbced69bf77a0e55a7fc/src/Symfony/Component/Mailer/Transport/Smtp/EsmtpTransportFactory.php#L56)

Comment: Where exactly do I add the `ping_threshold' => 10`? In `config/mail.php` I have this line `'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),`. In my app I do not have `ses` config file.

Comment: When I'm sending the email it does get sent but I still get the the error `Expected response code "250" but got code "451", with message "451 4.4.2 Timeout waiting for data from client.".`. If I send multiple emails on the row (with few sec between), I noticed that the error gets town after second email. But both emails go get delivered.

Comment: Symfony mentioned, adding `ping_threshold` should fix the issue. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/45586#issuecomment-1061073856

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the above answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71530024/16046216, setting `'ping_threshold' => 10` in `config/mail.php` works for me.

However, do NOT add it to `mailers` configuration for `smtp` or `ses`. Add this at the root level (same level at which `mailers` or `log_channel` are added) in the configuration file. Refer to below snapshot of `config/mail.php` configuration in Laravel project:

```
<?php

return [
    ...
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mailer Configurations
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    */

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' = [
            ...
        ],
        ...
    ],

    ...

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Transport Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    */
    'ping_threshold' => 10,
];
```

After debugging I found how the configuration options are read and setup in `\Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\Smtp\EsmtpTransportFactory` and `\Illuminate\Mail\MailManager::createSmtpTransport()`.

We were getting this error on production servers very frequently after upgrading to Laravel 9.x from 8.x. On the server, the emails are being sent through SES using the background queue (SQS) service.